# Maple - simplifying expression under a constraint

Tags: maple

I am working with functions $f_{a,b,c}(x,y,z)$ which depend on the (fixed) parameters $a,b,c$.

The parameters $a,b,c$ satisfy the identity $a+b+c=0$.
How do I enforce Maple to simplify the expressions under this constraint?

I tried writing something like

```
simplify(%) assuming a+b+c=0
```

but that did not work.
Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For equations as constraints, you could use:

simplify(%,{a+b+c=0});

If it don't make what you want, you could define your own simplification procedure.

https://de.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=simplify&L=G

https://de.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=simplify%2fdetails

https://de.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=simplify%2fsiderels